# Why do I get an error 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY) on anything other than my dev box?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com-interop

I've read plenty of answers on here about how to deal with the error 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY) that say that `regsvr` is the way to go and checking the registry to make sure that the dll I'm using is properly registered.

I've done all of this on computers other than my dev box but still nothing so here's what I have:

The DLL I'm trying to refer to was developed in VB6 (SP6) with the following settings:

- Single Threaded
- Upgrade ActiveX Controls
- Binary Compatibility

I'm trying to reference it from C# using .NET 4.0 and it all works swimmingly on the machine that I'm developing on, however, when I try to use the project on any other computer that has the dll installed in exact same way I get the error above.

### UPDATE:

This dll works fine, as I would want it to, when used from a VB6 application on all of the computers involved.

Can anyone please shed some light onto what is happening here and how I might solve it? I have the VB6 dll and can distribute it with my current project if that would help at all.

Many Thanks,

Gareth

Comment: I´m afraid to ask this - because it´s a simple question: x86 / x64?

Comment: Taking a dependency on a VB6 executable is getting to be a strong liability, time has not been kind to its components.  Best thing to do is to run the program in a VM so you can turn the clock back to the previous century.  If you don't want to do that then you'll need to gather evidence, use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see it reading the registry.  Pay attention to the Typelib key accesses, compare the good one on your machine against the bad one on a borken machine.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer - x86 only.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'll have a glance with SysInternals' Process Monitor and see what I can dig up thanks.

Comment: you do have the VB runtimes installed?

Comment: I do indeed, the non-dev boxes are running a VB6 application that communicates with the VB6 dll in question successfully.

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect this: the DLL does load on the system just not when referenced from C#

Comment: When you say x86 ... I assume you mean your C# is explicitly compiled to target x86 AND is running as a 32-bit process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71600/discussion-between-ridecar2-and-rob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this one out I think... Foolish me was trying to use the DLL in a background thread and even though it was an STA thread it wasn't my friend.